# Showing a SelectedItem's Property

Tags: c#, wpf

So I enabled a rightclick option for my DataGrid. I want to display just one property of the selecteditem but it's not behaving like how I would like. It displays my namespace and extra.

```
public class Paymentinfo
{
   public int PaymentNo { get; set; }
   public String Date { get; set; }
   public double Payment { get; set; }
   public double Principle { get; set; }
   public double Interest { get; set; }
   public double Balance { get; set; }
}

private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(AmortGrid.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

I am trying to implement this without using a viewmodel! If I put a breakpoint where Messagebox is and put the cursor over the selectedItem then it'll display the properties paymentNo-date-payment-principle-interest-balance. The only value I require is PaymentNo

was hoping it'd be something like this

```
MessageBox.Show(AmortGrid.SelectedItem.PaymentNo.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `ToString()` like that, you get the name of the class type, which is what you're seeing.

If that's a collection of `Paymentinfo`, cast `SelectedItem` back to that type first:

```
MessageBox.Show(((Paymentinfo)AmortGrid.SelectedItem).PaymentNo.ToString());
```

---

FWIW, I'd reconsider the `ViewModel`. Far easier to test your code if you get it out of the code-behind.

You'd be able to bind your `SelectedItem` directly to a property in the `ViewModel` (perhaps called SelectedPaymentinfo), and then there'd be no messing around with casting.

Comment: +1 for viewmodel and binding. It's a shame not to use such a powerful tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the [SelectedValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx) and instead of using SelectedItem use [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Create a ToString() method on PaymentInfo.

```
public class Paymentinfo
{
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return PaymentNo.ToString();
   }
}
```